# Печенье — 1 штука

Tags: словообразование

Пожалуйста, подскажите, какая верная словоформа для обозначения печенья, если речь идёт именно об 1 изделии.

Я нашла вариант "печеньице": Взял из корзины одно печеньице.

Верно ли это? Если да, то единственный ли это правильный вариант?

Answer (score 1):

Словари рассматривают это слово как уменьшительное от собирательного слова "печенье", поэтому иное употребление слова "печеньице", скорее всего, можно рассматривать как неформальное. Я в необходимых случаях всегда говорил "**печенина** (уменьш. **печенинка**)". Можно поиском по книгам найти *множество* литературных примеров, если искать в винительном падеже ("печенин**у**").

В последние годы стало часто употребляться слово "печенька", а вместо "печенье" - "печеньк**и**". Возможно, когда-нибудь это признают одним из формальных вариантов, но на упаковках пока что так не пишут.

Comment: В Нацкорпусе нашлось одно-единственное:  Взял печенину, откусил. [Сергей Носов. Фигурные скобки (2015)]

Comment: Скудная же там коллекция! И всего одну "печенинку" у них тоже  можно найти :)

Answer (score 0):

Печенье, печеньице, печенюшка, печенинка, печенька.

Печенье может быть как собирательным, так и конкретным существительным.

> [ПЕЧЕНЬЕ](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?game=x&all=x&word=%EF%E5%F7%E5%ED%FC%E5), -я; ср. 1. только ед. Разг. То, что испечено для пищевого потребления. Как вкусно пахнет печеньем! 2. собир. Кондитерское изделие из испечённого теста, имеющее определённую форму и рельеф. Предожить гостям сдобное п. Коробка печенья. Купить килограмм печенья. Наладить производство печенья. Сухое п. (приготовленное без добавления сахара). 3. мн.: печенья, -ний. Каждый отдельный кусочек такого изделия. Разломить п. Высыпать печенья горкой. <Печеньице, -а; ср. Уменьш.-ласк. ы

Поэтому "Взял из корзины одно печенье" — корректно. Примеры из Нацкорпуса:

> Леночка схватила пачку ― как только дотянулась, ведь была ремнями пристегнута, ― высыпала всю пачку на столик и стала ломать **одно печенье** за другим. [Маша Трауб. Семеновы (2009)]
>
> Иван взял **еще одно печенье** и вышел из кухни. [Андрей Житков. Супермаркет (2000)]
>
> Марина вынимает из коробки **еще одно печенье** и прячет в сумку, в небольшой целлофановый пакет. [Вячеслав Рыбаков. Хроники смутного времени (1998)]

"Одно печеньице" тоже употребимо (как уменьшительно-ласкательное от *печенье*). Из Нацкорпуса:

> К чаю подадут **два печеньица** из умопомрачительной коробки и одну заморскую конфетку. [Дарья Симонова. Легкие крылышки (2002)]
>
> И действительно, в левом верхнем ящике стола своего подчиненного он обнаружил **пару печеньиц**, аккуратненько завернутых в бумагу. [Петр Галицкий. Опасная коллекция (2000)]
>
> Скрипнула дверь без ручки ― треугольная скважина, вошел санитар и поставил на тумбочку стакан кефира, накрытый **тремя печеньицами** «Мария». [Аркадий Вайнер, Георгий Вайнер. Лекарство против страха (1987)]
>
> Саня отдал ему **последнюю печеньицу**. Малыш жадно схватил ее, шмыгнул на печку и оттуда закричал: [Виктор Курочкин. На войне как на войне (1965)]

Можно сказать "одна печенюшка", но словарь дает его с пометой "разговорное":

> [ПЕЧЕНЮШКА](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&ro=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8E%D1%88%D0%BA%D0%B0), -и; мн. род. -шек, дат. -шкам; ж. Разг. =Печенье (3 зн.).

Из Нацкорпуса:

> Саша насупился, достал **одну печенюшку** и положил на стол. [Маша Трауб. Плохая мать (2010)]
>
> ― мысленно отзывался **каждой печенюшке** и, только покончив с ними, удосужился прочесть: «Н… комсомолец», 20 августа…» [Виктор Слипенчук. Зинзивер (2001)]
>
> Так бедному родственнику заворачивают на дорогу **две печенюшки**. ) [Дина Рубина. Воскресная месса в Толедо (2000)]

Можно сказать "одна печенинка":

> Далее пути расходятся―часть девушек сходит с дистанции и возвращается к жизни, остальные «худеющие» еще сильнее ограничивают себя в еде (**1 печенинка** в три дня), начинают больше двигаться, почти не спят, чтобы «жир не накапливался». [Милана БОРИСОВА. Чтобы похудеть, москвички голодают до смерти // Комсомольская правда, 2003.04.21]
>
> Надо было съесть **печенинку** ― причаститься ― и запить черно-коричневой жидкостью из страшной, как казалось Славице, ложки в руке Аны. [Наталия Медведева. Любовь с алкоголем (1988-1993)]

Употребляют такве слово "печенька", но словарь говорит, что это сниженный стиль:

> [печенька](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&ro=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B0), -и, р. мн. -нек (одна штука печенья, сниж.)

Из Нацкорпуса:

> **Одну печеньку**. Вот эту, маленькую. [Андрей Белянин. Свирепый ландграф (1999)]
>
> Ты слюни не глотай и на **печеньки** не смотри, скоро пироги будут. [О. В. Колпакова. Большое сочинение про бабушку (2011)]

Comment: Тут ещё и "печеньица" (ж. р.) у одного из литераторов! А "ещё одно печенье" вне контекста воспринимается как "ещё один сорт печенья".

Comment: @Alex_ander А вариант приведенного в вопросе предложения "Взял из корзины одно **печенье**" воспринимается нормально?

Comment: Я воспринимаю плохо: то ли печенье особенно крупное (как пирожное - не зажать пальцами с двух сторон), то ли случай формальный (показания и т. п.). Впечатление примерно такое же, как от слов губернаторши Матвиенко (в бытность её таковой): а нельзя ли сбивать _сосули_ лазером?

Comment: В словарной статье удивило, что значение "кондитерское изделие" поставлено вторым (исторически позже появилось, но в современном языке это основное значение слова).

Comment: @Alex_ander А по-моему *печенье* звучит нейтрально (см. словарь) в отличие от уменьшительных, которые как бы подчеркивают малые размеры. Ну а *печенина* у меня не на слуху.

Comment: Нейтрально звучит в собирательном значении, но в значении элемента - есть некоторая напряженность, это значение не сразу "доходит", трудно даже сказать, одна ли штука (может, и две прихвачено). Печенина или печенинка - выбор может говорить о размере печенья (льдина - льдинка).